# How to remove contents of one file from another

Tags: bash

I have two strings that come from files with multiple lines (`$old` and `$new`). How do I remove all contents from `$new` that appear in `$old`?

Ex:

```
old:
    oranges
    apples
    oranges

new:
    oranges
    apples
    oranges
    pineapples

output:
    pineapples
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep` and process substitution:

```
grep -vxFf <(printf '%s' "$old") <(printf '%s' "$new")
```

- `-v` - retrieve lines that don't match
- `-x` - match the whole line
- `-F` - match as strings, not regex
- `-f` - read strings from file, not command line

Comment: They are actually strings from files: `new=$(awk '{print $1}' /var/log/apache2/access.log | sort -u)`